# why return the token name?

Tags: lex

```
%{
    #include "y.tab.h"
    extern int yylval;
%}
%%
    [0-9]+ {yylval = atoi (yytext); return NUM;}
    [ \t]  ;
    \n     return 0;
    .      return yytext[0];
%%
```

When I use yylval which is pointing to the value, why should I return the NUM? I mean what does NUM represent (NUM is decalred in YACC section)? Is NUM storing any value?

I am very confused with this section even when it has proper solution. I am just not getting the right reason for returning NUM as I have pointer yylval in YACC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NUM` is the token type. It's the *category* of the value rather than the value itself.

In other words, some of your own YACC code may not care *what* the actual value is, just that it's of a specific type.

A classic example is a (very) simple expression evaluator that takes `NUM` `+` `NUM`. You don't want a special rule for every case:

```
0 + 0
0 + 1
0 + 2
:
65535 + 65534
65535 + 65535
```

so you have *one* rule that handles the general case, then use `yylval` for the specific value.